# Is there a UI to grant access to roles in VS2013 database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project

In sql server explorer is a UI to grant roles access to read insert etc. on all tables.

When importing this into Visual Studio database project then it generates the grants below the tables. E.g.

```
GRANT INSERT
ON OBJECT::[dbo].[MyTable] TO [MyRole]
AS [dbo];
```

I can't seem to find any UI for it in Visual Studio though. Does anyone know if there is a UI?

Comment: You can usually generate the scripts out of an existing DB if that's a concern and if you use roles, it might be easier to manage the security overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such UI, at least as of Visual Studio 2013.